# Do rocket exhausts produce an electromagnetic signature to allow remote sensing of said rocket?

Tags: rockets, jupiter, remote-sensing, plasma, magnetosphere

Rocket exhaust contains ions, the composition of which varies depending on temperature and fuel. https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/3.27825 and https://www.eucass.eu/doi/EUCASS2017-434.pdf

[image: Figure 12 : Top: Mean value of electron number density computed with RANS approach and with LES approach on 8.4 M and 20 M grids (time and azimuthal average). Bottom: standard deviation of electron number density, and Abel transform of electron number density, on the axis https://www.eucass.eu/doi/EUCASS2017-434.pdf]

> Figure 12 : Top: Mean value of electron number density computed with RANS approach and with LES approach on
> 8.4 M and 20 M grids (time and azimuthal average).
> Bottom: standard deviation of electron number density, and Abel transform of electron number density, on the axis

Source: A Guy et al. (2017) [Ionized Solid Propellant Rocket Exhaust Plume:
MiLES Simulation and Comparison to Experiment](https://www.eucass.eu/doi/EUCASS2017-434.pdf) 7th European Conference for Aeronautics and Space Sciences (EUCASS)

These ions exit the nozzle at high speed along the axis of the exhaust plume. If this stream is discharged in a planetary magnetic field, positive and negative ions will be accelerated in opposite directions, at right angles to both the external magnetic field and the plume’s axis.

Acceleration of charged particles will generate an electric field across the plume, and will also generate electromagnetic radiation.

Generation of an electric field by an ion stream passing through a magnetic field is demonstrated by a Magnetohydrodynamic generator

[image]

Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_generator

Does this process generate a detectable electromagnetic signature which would allow remote sensing to identify the rocket’s design, distance or velocity?

Given Jupiter’s strong magnetic field, would this process have any significance for space exploration using chemical rockets in Jupiter’s vicinity?

Comment: Perhaps edit the title to indicate the part just after "allow remote sensing" as currently it's trivially true.